# Can Magento 1 coupon codes imported into Magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to import all Magento 1 cart rules in the new Magento 2 platform. can it possible with a migration tool or need to purchase an extension. if purchase please share the name of the extension.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. In addition, it is explicitly off-topic to ask us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: The better place to ask this kind of questions is Magento Forum or  https://magento.stackexchange.com/ , you can import coupons in any format with our commercial solution - would be happy to help https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-import-magento-2-cart-price-rules.html